# For loop in for loop - Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
l1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
l2 = ["a", "b", "c"]

for i in l1:
    print(i)
    for i in l2:
        print(i)
```

Output: `aabcbabccabc`
**How can I get an output like this?:**
`aabbcc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `zip` builtin function. It will return the `i-th item` of all the iterables you pass. See [zip doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=all#zip)

In your case:

```
for it in zip(l1, l2):
    # the * is for extracting the items from it
    # sep="" does not print any spaces between
    # end="" does avoid printing a new line at the end
    print(*it, sep="", end="")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip`:

```
l1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
l2 = ["a", "b", "c"]


for a, b in zip(l1, l2):
  print(a)
  print(b)
```

Comment: Thank you Ronie. This is what I need

Answer (score 0):

If the arrays are the same size, you can do something like this:

```
for i in range((len(l1)):
    print(l1[i])
    print(l2[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use zip function as below

```
print(*(y for x in zip(l1,l2) for y in x))
```